Will a 2-node windows server failover cluster go down if the disk witness owner crashes?
In a 2 node WSFC where Node 1 owns the disk witness, would Node 1 crashing result in the entire cluster going down (loss of quorum because only 1/3 votes remain)?
Or does disk witness ownership transfer to Node 2 regardless of whether Node 1 was powered down gracefully or not?

Is the disk resource independent of both nodes or it is a disk belonging to one of the two nodes?

How would I check? Currently, I see that the disk witness is owned by node 2, and in it's properties both node 1 and 2 are possible owners.

Assuming the disk witness is properly setup, the cluster should stay online. A regroup event will occur to ask for votes, it will be noticed that the surviving partition is 1 off quorum and will attempt to arbitrate for the witness. If the witness is successfully arbitrated, the votes needed for quorum will be achieved and the cluster will stay online.

Thank you. Is there any quick way to verify if the disk witness or underlying cluster disk is set up correctly? Validating the storage isn't currently an option because of a password policy error during validation (Failure while setting up to run Cluster Shared Volumes support testing on node [FQDN]. The password does not meet the password policy requirements.) For example, iSCSI under File and Storage Services in the server manager shows up as blank – is that a surefire indicator that the cluster disk/witness is not set up correctly?

@Marcus If the witness is using iSCSI then that's a problem. Running the cluster validation wizard on storage should give you output, having said that it'll move the disks to each node to validate them. If you don't want to go that route, you can manually move the core cluster resource group to the other node which will essentially achieve the same thing, you just need to check the output in the cluster log for the results and any issues.

I don't believe it is – is there an easy way to check? The issue I'm trying to resolve concerns error logs stating that the owner node lost control over the cluster disks (the cluster disk hosting a SQL Server FCI as well as one hosting the disk witness) due to what I assume were ungraceful shutdowns (no pre-shutdown failover done). If an ungraceful shutdown occurred and the node owning the SQL Server role as well as the cluster disks went down, would no failover occur until said node comes back online and rejoins the cluster?

Honestly it sounds like you have many more issues that might be affecting the setup. It's probably something you'll want to bring in a consultant or other professional to help with if you're having this many errors and issues.  @Marcus

It's a client's cluster, so my hands are a bit tied with what I can do. Switching to a file-share witness would resolve all of these issues and will probably be the path I take moving forward. I was just hoping to narrow down the disk witness behavior issues to figure out what caused the occasional error messages on ungraceful shutdowns.
